# SonarQUBE filter projects per language and bulk delete

Tags: filter, sonarqube, bulk

We need to uninstall a language plugin from SonarQUBE, and as a first step, we want to purge all project analysis configured with this language (not multi-language ones).

We have seen in project description, the language selected for this project, but is it possible to configure a filter per language and do a bulk deletion somehow?

Many thanks.

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was possible before SonarQube 4.2, but since the multi-language support has been added in 4.2, this is unfortunately no more possible.